# Having a problem when using unittest in VS Code

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a project with a structure like this:

```
    Battleship
    |
    ├── Files
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── Battleship.py
    └── Tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_battleship.py
```

In the `test_battleship.py` file, I have the import command:

```
from Battleship import *
```

But when I run the test in VS Code, I receive the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Battleship'
```

Can anyone show me how to properly import the Battleship files? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/15091435

Comment: Yes, I was able to import it after using
`import sys sys.path.append('../')`